# Trait bound T: From<Result<T, Error>> is not satisfied

Tags: rust, traits

I want to load `nonce` from a toml config file.  `nonce` is retrieved in `pub fn get_nonce()`. I'd like to instantiate the result to `salt` of lazy_static macro type `HarshBuilder`.

```
use config::{Config, File, FileFormat, ConfigError};
use harsh::{Harsh, HarshBuilder};
use settings::Server;

const CFG_DEFAULT: &'static str = "conf/default";

lazy_static! {
    static ref MASK: Harsh = HarshBuilder::new()
        .length(7)
        .salt(get_nonce())
        .init()
        .expect("invalid harsh build");
}

fn conf_file() -> Config {
    let mut cfg = Config::default();
    cfg.merge(File::from_str(CFG_DEFAULT, FileFormat::Toml))
        .unwrap();

    cfg
}

pub fn get_nonce() -> Result<Vec<u8>, ConfigError> {
    let conf = conf_file();
    let search: Server = conf.get("server").unwrap();
    let nonce: Vec<u8> = search.nonce.into_bytes();

    Ok(nonce)
}
```

The compiler returns an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u8>: std::convert::From<std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u8>, config::ConfigError>>` is not satisfied
--> lib.rs:40:14
|
40 |     .salt(get_nonce())
|         ^^^^ the trait 
|
`std::convert::From<std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u8>, config::ConfigError>>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u8>`

|
= help: the following implementations were found:
         <std::vec::Vec<u8> as std::convert::From<std::ffi::CString>>
         <std::vec::Vec<u8> as std::convert::From<std::string::String>>
         <std::vec::Vec<T> as std::convert::From<&'a mut [T]>>
         <std::vec::Vec<T> as std::convert::From<std::borrow::Cow<'a, [T]>>>
       and 5 others
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<std::vec::Vec<u8>>` for `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u8>, config::ConfigError>`
```

So `get_nonce()` returns an enum result of `Result<String, ConfigError>`.  This does not appear to satisfy `salt Option<Vec<u8>>`.  The attempt you see above is to convert `Result` enum to `Vec<u8>`.  However, this does not fix the error.

Here is the `HarshBuilder` trait implementation for review:

```
/// Note that this factory will be consumed upon initialization.
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct HarshBuilder {
    salt: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    // ...ommitted for brevity
}

impl HarshBuilder {
/// Creates a new `HarshBuilder` instance.
pub fn new() -> HarshBuilder {
    HarshBuilder {
        salt: None,
        // ...ommited for brevity
    }
}

/// Note that this salt will be converted into a `[u8]` before use, meaning
/// that multi-byte utf8 character values should be avoided.
pub fn salt<T: Into<Vec<u8>>>(mut self, salt: T) -> HarshBuilder {
    self.salt = Some(salt.into());
    self
}
```

Trait bounds and lifetime elision is still a subject that I'm trying to wrap my head around.  I can really use some guidance.  Perhaps, this may be the reason as to why the answer is not completely obvious for me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Option<Vec<u8>>` is a red herring, the important thing is the prototype of `salt()`, and as you can see in the definition of `salt`:

```
pub fn salt<T: Into<Vec<u8>>>(mut self, salt: T)
```

it expects an argument that satisfies the trait `Into<Vec<u8>>`. From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) you can see that there are these generic implementations of `Into<T>`:

- `From<T>`for `U` implies `Into<U>` for `T`
- `Into` is reflexive, which means that `Into<T>` for `T` is implemented.

So you may pass to `salt` either:

- A value of type `Vec<u8>`.
- A value of type `T` if there is such `From<T>` is implemented for `Vec<u8>`.
- A value that implements `Into<Vec<u8>>` directly.

Now, you have a value of type `Result<Vec<u8>, ConfigError>`, that satisfies none of the above. And that is what all those error messages are trying to tell you.

The easy solution is to change your function into:

```
pub fn get_nonce() -> Vec<u8> {
     ....
     nonce
}
```

If you cannot change that return type you can use `unwrap()` to get the real value from a `Result()` (and crash on error):

```
    .length(7)
    .salt(get_nonce().unwrap())
    .init()
```

If the `get_nonce()` function can really fail, then you would have to manage the error properly, maybe making your `MASK` value of type `Result<Harsh, ConfigError>`?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `get_nonce` function returns a `Result`, you need to handle the possible error. There are three ways you can fix your code here:

- Given that `get_nonce` never returns an error, you can simply change it so that it returns `nonce` directly instead of `Ok(nonce)`.
- Or you can call `unwrap` on the result to access the `Vec<u8>` that's inside (and crash if you later change `get_nonce` to generate errors).
- Or you can add proper error handling all around (get rid of the `unwrap`s and use `try!` or the `?` operator to propagate errors and catch them properly at some top-level point).